# Stop playback after a specific time using Javascript

Tags: javascript, video

I'm building a mobile game with Twine (a storytelling engine that uses html, css and javascript) and would like to start playback of a background-video for 5 seconds via the push of a button. After 5sec the video should pause. If I hit the button again the video should continue for another 5sec (moving further down the timeline) and then pause agin.

This is what I have so far.

```
<video id="myVideo">
  <source src="./video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script> 
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    
function playVid() { 
  vid.play(); 
} 

</script> 

<button onclick="playVid()" type="button">Play Video</button>
```

Can anybody help out?

Thx a lot

Comment: PS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener Also, `<script>` should be **right before the closing `</body>`** tag, not disseminated around your document in a render-blocking manner. So, yeah, stop using inline `on*` handlers, just like you hopefully don't use inline `style` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use `on*` inline attribute handlers. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead
- Place your `<script>` tag in a non render-blocking manner, right before the closing `</body>` tag.
- Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) to *schedule* a function call, or perform some code — after *N* milliseconds

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par||document).querySelector(sel);


// Task:

const elVideo = el("#myVideo");
const elPlayVideo = el("#playVideo");
const timePause = 5000; // ms time to pause
let playTimeout;

const playVideo = () => { 
  clearTimeout(playTimeout);   // Clear any occurring timeouts
  elVideo.play();              // Play video
  elPlayVideo.disabled = true; // Disable click

  playTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    elVideo.pause();              // Pause video
    elPlayVideo.disabled = false; // Enable button click
  }, timePause);                  // Wait N milliseconds
};

elPlayVideo.addEventListener("click", playVideo);
```

```css
video {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ahmetaksungur/aksvideoplayer/main/videos/video-360.mp4"></video>
<button id="playVideo" type="button">Play Video</button>
<!-- Stop using inline on* handlers attributes. -->

<!-- <script> should go here, right before the closing `</body>` tag. -->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did it! That the button is disabled during the playback is also great.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `setTimeout` function - after `vid.play()`.

It schedules a function to run after a specified amount of time, and returns a reference to the timer so you can cancel it by calling `clearTimeout`.

You will probably want to consider what you want to happen if someone clicks the button while the video is playing too.